# Return number of CPU sockets, Cores, and Threads in Golang

Tags: go, psutil

Using Golang I'm trying to find/write a function that would return the number of CPU Sockets, Cores per socket, and Threads per core a Linux system.  For example, a server might have 2 CPUs each with 4 cores, with hyperthreading, it could handle 8 threads per CPU.

Sample Output:

```
{
  "CPUSockets": "2",
  "CoresPerSocket": "4",
  "ThreadsPerCore": "2"
}
```

**Question:**  Do you know of any Go Package or pseudo code that could provide this information?

**Note:** I've looked at various go implementations of psutil but I can't find one that returns the number of sockets or distinguishes between Cores and Threads.  The data I want is very easily accessible by running `lscpu` but I don't know how to access that using Go.

Comment: Do you want it to be platform agnostic? If it's just for Linux, you can settle for reading `/proc/cpuinfo` or even running `lscpu` itself.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up figuring it out, see below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type CPUInfo struct {
    Sockets        int32 `json:"sockets"`
    CoresPerSocket int32 `json:"cores_per_socket"`
    ThreadsPerCore int32 `json:"threads_per_core"`
}

func main() {
    out, _ := exec.Command("lscpu").Output()
    outstring := strings.TrimSpace(string(out))
    lines := strings.Split(outstring, "\n")
    c := CPUInfo{}

    for _, line := range lines {
        fields := strings.Split(line, ":")
        if len(fields) < 2 {
            continue
        }
        key := strings.TrimSpace(fields[0])
        value := strings.TrimSpace(fields[1])

        switch key {
        case "Socket(s)":
            t, _ := strconv.Atoi(value)
            c.Sockets = int32(t)
        case "Core(s) per socket":
            t, _ := strconv.Atoi(value)
            c.CoresPerSocket = int32(t)
        case "Thread(s) per core":
            t, _ := strconv.Atoi(value)
            c.ThreadsPerCore = int32(t)
        }
    }

    CPUInfoJSON, _ := json.MarshalIndent(c, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(CPUInfoJSON))
}
```

Output:

```
tbenz9@ubuntu-dev: go run socket.go 
{
  "sockets": 1,
  "cores_per_socket": 2,
  "threads_per_core": 2
}
```

Comment: you can also just read /proc/cpuinfo, which might be a little more straight forward than running a command line tool and parsing its output

Comment: @DavidBudworth `lscpu` exists because it is an impossible task for us mere mortals to reliably render the content of `/proc/cpuinfo` across all platforms and CPU models.

Comment: I'd think that `lscpu`'s output would be more likely to change than the kernel's `/proc/cpuinfo` given that a kernel change would break tons of tools.   But, maybe there's also a ton of stuff parsing `lscpu` output, so it's stable as well